# firebird - getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND

Tags: node.js, firebird, node-firebird

I am new to firebird database.

I have created a database "a" and a table "STUDENT".

I am trying to connect to the database using this npm package
https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-firebird

Following is my code to connect to db and get data.

```
    var Firebird = require('node-firebird');
var options = {};
options.host = '127.0.0.1:c:\a.fdb';
options.port = 3050;
options.database = 'a';
options.user = 'SYSDBA';
options.password = 'sa123';
options.role = null; // default 
options.pageSize = 4096; // default when creating database 

app.get('/', function(request, response) {
    Firebird.attach(options, function(err, db) {
        if (err)
            console.log(err);//her i get error
        db.query('SELECT * FROM student', function(err, result) {
            console.log(result);
            db.detach();
        });

    });
});
```

I am using flameRobin.
Following are my database properties

[image]

I get following error in node console.

```
{ [Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND 127.0.0.1:c:a.fdb 127.0.0.1:c:a.fdb:3050]
  code: 'ENOTFOUND',
  errno: 'ENOTFOUND',
  syscall: 'getaddrinfo',
  hostname: '127.0.0.1:c:a.fdb',
  host: '127.0.0.1:c:a.fdb',
  port: 3050 }
```

help me.

Comment: Which Firebird version are you using. Firebird 2.5 and earlier do not support IPv6 addresses.

Comment: i am using Firebird 3.0

Comment: Is it something related to permissions?

Comment: The problem seems to be that your entire connection string is getting parsed as an IPv6 address, not sure how to solve it though, as I haven't used node.js nor node-firebird.

Comment: HI @MARKANDBhatt, did you find a solution to this problem? I'm having the same problem. Thanks.

Comment: ThiagoPXP : Nope

Answer (score 4):

try :

```
options.host = '127.0.0.1'; or options.host = 'localhost';
```

instead of

```
options.host = '127.0.0.1:c:\a.fdb';
```

and

```
options.database = 'c:\a.fdb';
```

instead of

```
options.database = 'a';
```

Comment: Nope. Didn't work. options.host = 'localhost';
options.database='d:\\a.fdb';
options.user = 'sysdba';
options.password = 'sa123'; This time i get "[Connection is Closed]" error

Comment: `options.database='d:\\a.fdb'` ? is this tipo or ...? Do you mean `options.database='d:\a.fdb'` ?

Comment: no its not typo. its because '\'(single \) is considered as escape sequence.

Answer (score 2):

Try `localhost:c:\a.fdb` as your host and hostname

Comment: i tried following options.host = 'localhost:c:\a.fdb' but unsuccessful

Comment: Is your base node.JS app is listening on a port successfully?

Comment: Yes. it is listening

Comment: have you tried just connecting the DB to localhost without the c:/a.b?

Comment: Yes, I tried it. This i get different error. I get "connection closed" error